# Yii : How to make a button with an html tag inside the label

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm trying to use some bootstrap features like the Icon glyphs in the Yii CHtml class, here is my code:

```
<?php 
   echo CHtml::submitButton('<i class="icon-user"></i> Login', 
       array(
           'class' => 'btn btn-large pull-right'
       )); 
 ?>
```

But it kinda don't "recognize" the  tag and just renders the tag out like the image bellow .[image]

does anyone knows how to workaround it (without typing the html tags itself).

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`CHtml::submitButton` produces an `<input type="submit">` that cannot accept additional HTML as its content. However, you can do things to taste with `CHtml::tag`:

```
echo CHtml::tag('button',
                array('class' => 'btn btn-large pull-right'),
                '<i class="icon-user"></i> Login');
```

This will produce a `<button>` tag that can take arbitrary HTML as its content.

**Update:** As frostyterrier points out in the comments, there's a built-in method [`CHtml::htmlButton`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#htmlButton-detail) that allows you to do this even more easily:

```
echo CHtml::htmlButton('<i class="icon-user"></i> Login',
                       array('class' => 'btn btn-large pull-right'));
```

Comment: Couldn't he use http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#button-detail? I normally add type="submit" as well for cross-browser compatibility reasons.

Comment: @frostyterrier: `CHtml::button` has the tag hardcoded as `<input>`. AFAIK there's no compatibility problem with `<button>` at least as far back as IE 7.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I meant this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#htmlButton-detail

Comment: @frostyterrier: You 're right, I somehow missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Great !!! I got it by adding the "type" property as submit : 

<?php echo CHtml::htmlButton('<i class="icon-user"></i> Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-large pull-right', 'type' => 'submit')); 

?>

and now it works :D
Thank you all guys !!

Answer (score 3):

Try to set 'encode' to false in htmlOptions parameter.

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::submitButton('<i class="icon-user"></i> Login',
        array(
            'encode' => false,
            'class' => 'btn btn-large pull-right'
        ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`CHTML::submitbutton` generates `<intput type="submit" />` tag and you're trying to cram HTML into its `value` attribute.

Why don't you simply add the `icon-user` CSS class to the button itself?

```
echo CHtml::submitButton('Login', array(
   'class' => 'btn btn-large pull-right icon-user'
));
```

If it's a Bootstrap-defined class, it should style the input button nicely.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->widget("bootstrap.widget.TbButton", array(
'buttonType'=>'submit',
'label=>'Login',
'type'=>'success', //or default or warning... as you like
'icon'=>'user',
'size'=>'large', //small, mini, or just comment line for default

));
```

documentation: http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbButton

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should change from subbmitButton to htmlButton,for example write the following code:

```
<?php echo CHtml::htmlButton('<span>Log in!</span>',array('type'=>'submit','class'=>'tbutton small pad')); ?>
```